# W3 validation, last leg

Tags: html

I'm doing some w3 validation. I've done most of the work as I started with 40 reported issues, now is only 3.

This is the page I'm validating:

```
 <?php
session_start();
ob_start();
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->


<html>
<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Andrew's Webpage</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">


<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
    ================================================== -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/navcss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/map.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/about.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicons
        ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-    114x114.png">

</head>

<body>
<div id= "background">
<div id = "main-head" class="container">
        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Advanced Internet Development A </h1>
            <h5>Andrew David Dunkerley</h5>
                <h6> <a href="loginform.php">Login</a></h6>
                <h6> <a href="register.php">Register</a></h6>   
                <h6> <a href="cart.php">Cart</a></h6>





    </div>
    </div>
       </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and these are the errors im getting. its probably something so simple but something i keep missing.

- Error Line 10, Column 6: Stray start tag html.

  ```
  <html>
  ```
- Error Line 66, Column 36: Stray start tag div.

  ```
  </html><div class="sixteen columns">
  ```
- Error Line 66, Column 36: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

  ```
  </html><div class="sixteen columns">
  ```

Comment: You/re opening html twice, skeleton already opens it and you open it again

Comment: dude, your html tag is duplicated

Comment: Your `<!DOCTYPE>` should be the first thing, but there is whitespace before it.

Comment: Replace `<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->` with `<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->` and `assets/images/apple-touch-icon-    114x114.png` with `assets/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png` and it'll validate with `Using Direct Input mode: UTF-8 character encoding assumed` warning. (you can specify the encoding to fix that warning too)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Andrew's Webpage</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/base.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/skeleton.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/layout.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/navcss.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/map.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/about.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id= "background">
            <div id = "main-head" class="container">
                <div class="sixteen columns">
                    <h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Advanced Internet Development A </h1>
                    <h5>Andrew David Dunkerley</h5>
                    <h6> <a href="loginform.php">Login</a></h6>
                    <h6> <a href="register.php">Register</a></h6>   
                    <h6> <a href="cart.php">Cart</a></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the duplicated html resolved one error , this is just the last errors

Comment: Error Line 66, Column 36: Stray start tag div.

</html><div class="sixteen columns">
Error Line 66, Column 36: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

</html><div class="sixteen columns">

Comment: @user3542382 where is line 66 **in question**

Comment: its the 3rd </div> tag but i think its related to the <div id= "background">
<div id = "main-head" class="container">
  <div class="sixteen columns"> section

Comment: 2nd and 3rd ERROR mention in question is not found in code in question

Comment: @user3542382 try this `</html><div class="sixteen columns">` **instead use this** `<div class="sixteen columns"></html>` and second error `</html><div class="sixteen columns">` **instead use like this** `<div class="sixteen columns"></html>`