# Validating a page in w3

Tags: php, validation

Hey i have a problem with a few errors on my page i had more but ive worked through them

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en"><![endif]-->



<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Andrew's Webpage</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/navcss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/map.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/about.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

</head>

<body>
<div id= "background">
<div id= "main-head" class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
            <h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Advanced Internet Development A </h1>

            <h5>Andrew David Dunkerley</h5>
            <h6> <a href="loginform.php">Login</a></h6>
            <h6> <a href="register.php">Register</a></h6>   
            <h6> <a href="cart.php">Cart</a></h6>


</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

the errors i get are Error Line 66, Column 36: Stray start tag div.

✉
Error Line 66, Column 36: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

Comment: You realise that w3c validates the markup generated by your script, not the script itself

Comment: You've asked this precise thing already today... like maybe 1 or 2 hours ago... that aside, i put your script in the w3c validator and it came back valid. what kind of validator are you using?

Comment: **hello bro** here is your first question [CHECK THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889355/w3-validation-last-leg/27889497?noredirect=1#comment44180556_27889497)